# rhino-mocks - good sample apps

Tags: .net, testing, ado.net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I know that there has been a couple questions about tutorials on rhino-mocks. But I am wondering if there are any sample apps out there that use rhino-mocks in the context of an n-tier business application using ado.net.

I find the tutes good, but they don't seem to bring everything all together into the big picture. Thus, I am looking for a sample app that brings the full picture together.

Also, I think there is a little bit of a lack of examples which specifically deal with mocking and testing the logic in the data access layer.

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 2):

I have a demo app from a talk I gave on testing.  It does some mocking with Rhino Mocks.  You can download it if you would like:

http://www.houseofbilz.com/archive/2008/10/18/gui-testing-resources.aspx

Comment: +1 for your work. Please, add some more details in your answer in which tests one should look :)

Comment: Look in the RecipeBox.Tests project.  The tests that use mocks are:  RecipeBoxLogicTests.cs and GUITests\ReciptBoxGUIUnitTests*.cs

Answer (score 1):

[Rhino Mocks Documentation](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx)
[TDD : Introduction to Rhino Mocks](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/03/22/tdd-introduction-to-rhino-mocks.aspx)

Using Google you will fine more. 
You should try to understand mocking, and that it's purpose is to make testing possible by [Mocking](http://www.answers.com/mocking) some lower layer. It provides means of splitting **big picture** in lots of independent smaller pictures. That way you are able to test business layer without hitting database.

[Stackoverflow: What is a mock and when should you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214092/what-is-a-mock-and-when-should-you-use-it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do have a fairly good grasp of mocking its just that I havn't been able to find an end to end example.